# Missing IN or OUT parameter in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle12c, oracle-service-bus

Im getting an error on this parte of SQL{ "U" = UPPER(:codigo) }. When i remove the variable and hardcode :codigo as u or U it works fine. The erro i receive is Missing In or Out parameter. I'm  receiving this error on Oracle 12c Service Bus

Full SQL:

```
    SELECT Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Tipo_Local, Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Loc_Amostg, Resultado_Ensaio.Prod_Cd_Id, Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Dh_Amostra,
              Resultado_Ensaio.Reen_Md_Res_Num, Componente_Gas_Nat.Cpgn_Nm_Abreviado,
              Caract_Produto.Capr_Nm_Completo,
              Unidade_Medida_Emq.Unme_Sg_Notacao, Metodo_Ensaio.Prme_Cd_Id, Metodo_Ensaio.Meen_Cd_Id,
              Resultado_Ensaio.Reen_Cd_Res_Alfa_E, Resultado_Ensaio.Tiam_Cd_Id, Caract_Produto.Capr_Cd_Comp_Carac,
              Caract_Produto.Capr_Cd_Id
              , Ce.AMOS_NR_CERT_QUAL, Ce.AMOS_DT_CERT_QUAL
          FROM Caract_Produto
          INNER JOIN Resultado_Ensaio ON (Caract_Produto.Capr_Cd_Id = Resultado_Ensaio.Capr_Cd_Id
              AND Caract_Produto.Capr_Cd_Comp_Carac = Resultado_Ensaio.Capr_Cd_Comp_Carac
              AND Caract_Produto.Grcp_Cd_Id = Resultado_Ensaio.Grcp_Cd_Id)
          INNER JOIN Metodo_Ensaio ON (Metodo_Ensaio.Meen_Cd_Id = Resultado_Ensaio.Meen_Cd_Id
              AND Metodo_Ensaio.Prme_Cd_Id = Resultado_Ensaio.Prme_Cd_Id)
          INNER JOIN Unidade_Medida_Emq Unidade_Medida_Emq ON (Unidade_Medida_Emq.Gume_Cd_Id = Resultado_Ensaio.Gume_Cd_Id
              AND Unidade_Medida_Emq.Unme_Cd_Id = Resultado_Ensaio.Unme_Cd_Id)
          LEFT JOIN Caract_Produto_Componente ON (Caract_Produto_Componente.Grcp_Cd_Id = Resultado_Ensaio.Grcp_Cd_Id
              AND Caract_Produto_Componente.Capr_Cd_Id = Resultado_Ensaio.Capr_Cd_Id
              AND Caract_Produto_Componente.Capr_Cd_Comp_Carac = Resultado_Ensaio.Capr_Cd_Comp_Carac)
          LEFT JOIN Componente_Gas_Nat ON (Caract_Produto_Componente.Cpgn_Cd_Id = Componente_Gas_Nat.Cpgn_Cd_Id)
          LEFT JOIN Certificado_Ensaio Ce ON (Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Loc_Amostg = Ce.Amos_Cd_Loc_Amostg
              AND Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Tipo_Local = Ce.Amos_Cd_Tipo_Local
              AND Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Dh_Amostra = Ce.Amos_Dh_Amostra
              AND Resultado_Ensaio.Tiam_Cd_Id = Ce.Tiam_Cd_Id
              AND Resultado_Ensaio.Prod_Cd_Id = Ce.Prod_Cd_Id
              AND Resultado_Ensaio.Prco_Cd_Comp_Prod = Ce.Prco_Cd_Comp_Prod
              AND Resultado_Ensaio.Orga_Cd_Cbi_Exec = Ce.Orga_Cd_Cbi_Exec)
          WHERE
              Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Tipo_Local    = (:tipo)
--------------AND ('U' = UPPER(:posicao) AND-------------------------------
              Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Dh_Amostra       = (
                      SELECT MAX(Reen2.Amos_Dh_Amostra)
                      FROM Resultado_Ensaio Reen2
                      WHERE Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Loc_Amostg = Reen2.Amos_Cd_Loc_Amostg
                          AND Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Tipo_Local = Reen2.Amos_Cd_Tipo_Local
                          AND Reen2.Amos_Dh_Amostra <= TO_TIMESTAMP('1999-11-01 07:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
                  )
                  OR
------------------'P' = UPPER(:posicao) AND--------------------------------
                  Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Dh_Amostra       = (
                      SELECT MIN(Reen2.Amos_Dh_Amostra)
                      FROM Resultado_Ensaio Reen2
                      WHERE Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Loc_Amostg = Reen2.Amos_Cd_Loc_Amostg
                          AND Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Tipo_Local = Reen2.Amos_Cd_Tipo_Local
                          AND Reen2.Amos_Dh_Amostra >= TO_TIMESTAMP('1999-11-01 07:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
                  )
                 )
                 AND Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Loc_Amostg like '314TQ5901%'
          ORDER BY Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Dh_Amostra, Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Loc_Amostg, Caract_Produto.Capr_Nm_Completo
```

Comment: need more context, where is the rest of your code? what are you trying to do?

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: Added Full SQL. There's something wrong when i compare "U" = :posicao , even if :posicao = "U".

Comment: `WHERE
              Resultado_Ensaio.Amos_Cd_Tipo_Local` <<-- this will degrade your LEFT join to a plain join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was: 
Each time variable :posicao was referenced my request need to have the same exact number of variables

let $dbInput := posicao1, posicao2

Even if posicao1 and posicao2 got the same values. 
Oracle Service Bus works like this when calling DbAdapters